# Target class [Livewire\Controllers\LivewireJavaScriptAssets] does not exist

Tags: laravel-livewire

I've just updated my Laravel project to use Livewire 3. Everything works fine on my local (Laravel Valet) after the update. However, when I deploy to my Digital Ocean server running Forge, I'm seeing a blank screen. In my logs I'm getting this error:

```
(ReflectionException(code: -1): Class \"Livewire\\Controllers\\LivewireJavaScriptAssets\" does not exist at /home/forge/mysite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:912)
```

Why is this happening on my forge site, but not my local?